# custom data filter in angular-ui-grid

Tags: angular, angular-ui, angular-ui-grid

```
{
    "grossValue": 500,
    "items": [
        {
            "billNo": "3",
            "name": "coke",
            "id": 556,
            "billAmount": 150,
            "quantity": 1,
            "ingredientType": {
                "isNonVeg": false,
                "isAlcoholic": false,
                "isBeverage": false
            }
        },
        {
            "billNo": "4",
            "name": "hot dogs",
            "id": 586,
            "billAmount": 247,
            "quantity": 1,
            "ingredientType": {
                "isNonVeg": false,
                "isAlcoholic": false,
                "isBeverage": false
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I have this `JSON` coming from database by a requested `URL`
and I want to show a column in last showing ingredientType
which shows "veg" if all of `Boolean` values is false in that last column's cell.

Problem is that I am unable to bind value of a function to that particular column's cell in `columnDefs` array,

```
columnDefs: [
    {field: 'billNo'},
    {field: 'name'},
    {field: 'id'},
    {field: 'billAmount'},
    {field: 'quantity'},
    {field: 'ingredientType'}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this is what you want. This basic example will log the row to your console output.

```
$scope.myFunction = function(rowEntity) {
    console.log('$scope.myFunction called', rowEntity);
}

var actionTemplate = '<button ng-click="grid.appScope.myFunction(row.entity)">MyFunction</button>';

columnDefs: [
    {field: 'billNo'},
    {field: 'name'},
    {field: 'id'},
    {field: 'billAmount'},
    {field: 'quantity'},
    {field: 'ingredientType'},
    {
      field: 'actions',
      displayName: 'Actions',
      cellTemplate: actionTemplate
    }
]
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but what you are giving me an another column which adds function in every cell of that column.

what i want is that last column ingredientType column should display "veg" in that cell if all of three entry is false in coming json data.

see example below

http://plnkr.co/edit/mENGgEicom7E3m89JPjV?p=preview

Comment: hi brian can you tell me why this doesn't work on ui.grid
http://plnkr.co/edit/jAyqrKZ6gGa4Xrp7NRsq?p=preview

as in this example a function is passed in columdef, i am trying to achieve similar thing but i can't.